# Base and derved class c++11

Tags: class, c++11, reference, derived-class, base-class

I have base class `Aclass` and derived class `Bclass`. If I create object `Bclass b` and if I write `A &aref(b)` is &aref now object of a class A or class B?

Comment: A reference is a reference and not an object.

Comment: but reference on what?

Comment: On whatever you made it point to, b in this case.  No copy was made. A reference is like a pointer with limited power, and some (but not much) added safety.  By convention, references are used as pointers that should not be null (even though it's possible to make it so) when passed as parameters, or to hold a pointer to a known good object to make code more readable while avoiding to make a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> &aref now object of a class A or class B?

It is a bit ambiguous what you mean by `&aref`. Regardless how it can be interpreted, it is neither an object of A nor B.

`aref` is a variable. The type of the variable is *reference*. It is not an object. More specifically, it is a reference to type `A`. However, it refers to an object of type `B`<sup>†</sup>.

`&aref` on the other hand is an expression using the address-of operator (`&`). The type of this expression is a pointer, and the value is the address of the object referred by `aref`.

---

<sup>†</sup> More technically, `aref` actually directly refers to the object of type `A` that is the parent subobject of an object of type `B`. But from the object oriented perspective, there is no difference.